# plotly.js: How to determine the start and end of axes range

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

How to get this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`layout.xaxis.range`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-range) and [`layout.yaxis.range`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#layout-yaxis-range):

```js
const layout = {
    xaxis: {
        range: [0, 100], // https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-range
    },
    yaxis: {
        range: [0, 100],
    }
}

Plotly.newPlot( 'myDiv', data, layout, config)
```